# Greatest Integer Function - solve for real $x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve for real $x$: $[x^2]=[2x-1]$ where $[x]$ is floor/box function.

Comment: Please, change the title. This equation doesn't seem me great at all. Better write there something objective about the function.

Comment: @Hume2 the greatest integer function is an actual function. It takes a number and rounds **up** to the nearest integer. So for example $\lceil \pi \rceil = 4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each integer, solve these equations and then make an intersection of both intervals:
$[x^2]=n$ and $[2x-1]=n$

You get:

for n = 0: $\bigl(-1;1\bigr)\cap\bigl<\frac12;1\bigr) = \bigl<\frac12;1\bigl)$

for n = 1: $\bigl<1;\sqrt2\bigr)\cap\bigl<1;\frac32\bigr) = \bigl<1;\sqrt2\bigl)$

for n = 2: $\bigl<\sqrt2;\sqrt3\bigr)\cap\bigl<\frac32;2\bigr) = \bigl<\frac32;\sqrt3\bigl)$

for n = 3: $\bigl<\sqrt3;2\bigr)\cap\bigl<2;\frac52\bigr) = \emptyset$

After that, you can simply proove that there are no other sollutions. The sollution is the union of all these sets:
$$\bigl<\frac12;\sqrt2\bigr)\cup\bigl<\frac32;\sqrt3\bigr)$$

Comment: What symbol is this $\bigl<\frac12$. What does it mean? Closed intervals?

Comment: Yes, it means a closed interval.